# How to get the folder path from a file input?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I need to access the folder path using HTML input file control. Is there any way to do this?
As far as I know, due to security concerns, end user is unable to access the folder path. Is there any plugin that I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot access the path where the uploaded file is located on the user's filesystem. As you said, it is not available for security reasons - so it's kind of obvious that there is no plugin that can achieve it.

But usually there is no point in accessing the path anyway - you have the file and its name. That should usually be enough.